# ¿Cómo puedo sincronizar Bitbucket con Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, bitbucket, control-de-versiones

¿He de añadir todos los directorios al control de versiones? ¿o sólo el directorio "wp-content"?

Por otro lado, ¿Sólo con hacer el pull obtengo los cambios suficientes para seguir trabajando en el proyecto en local y poder desplegarlo?

---

Uno de mis problemas es que a la hora de realizar el trabajo colaborativo, si otra persona hace un "pull" del proyecto no se aplican los cambios en su editor de wordpress.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Ademas lee: **[¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**

Answer (score 1):

Yo tengo dos versiones de trabajo para cuando hago un respositorio de wordpress.

**Primera versión**
Esta forma de trabajar es posiblemente la que menos me gusta pero la más rápida.
Genero un repositorio de todo el proyecto: wp-admin, wp-includes, wp-content y los archivos del index.
En el .gitignore pongo el uploads y las cachés.
Con esto tienes todo sincronizado pero es importante que la primera subida la hagas con el uploads y luego lo quites. Para que en local no haya problemas con las imágenes me pongo en mi htaccess lo siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^.*\.(gif|jpg|png)$ http(s)://(www.)tudominio.loquesea/$0 [L,R]
```

Con esto consigues que las imágenes no las tienes en local pero las carga directamente de producción, así puedes trabajar en local y replicar en otras máquinas sin tener que bajarte todo el contenido de imágenes y archivos.

**Segunda versión**
En esta versión lo que hacemos es generar un repositorio para tu wordpress base lo que significa tu versión de wordpress que uses, en mi caso tengo un wordpress base de 4.3 y todos mis proyectos los trabajo sobre esta versión.
Luego te creas un repositorio para tu carpeta de plugins donde iran los plugins por proyectos, de esta forma si hay algún cambio en los plugins no afecta al resto y solo has de subir y bajar en sus respectivos repositorios.
Lo mismo para los themes.
Con esto consigues que como el wordpress base no hay tantos cambios puedas actualizar entre versiones de una forma super rápida y tienes aislados los themes y los plugins que al final es donde deberías de trabajar.
El tema de uploads y caché el mismo funcionamiento que en la primera versión.

---

Estas dos son mis formas de trabajar y me van bastante bien ambas. Trabajo sobre vvv y ahí tengo mis repos funcionando, cuando hago un plugin siempre lo trabajo sobre proyectos limpios para cuando instale en un wordpress ya funcionando tenga la certeza de que funcione y también le hago un repositorio, pero luego tengo mis repos de plugins por proyecto.

Espero que te sirve mi respuesta :)

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Y cómo instalas los repos de plugins y themes? Aplicas submodules?

Comment: Primero clono el primer repo que sería el de la versión de wordpress. Luego creo el wp-content, y ahí clono los otros dos repos. En el general tengo un ignore de wp-content.

Comment: Uno de mis problemas es que a la hora de realizar el trabajo colaborativo, si otra persona hace un "pull" del proyecto no se aplican los cambios en su editor de wordpress.

¿Habría que exportar la base de datos o algo así?

Gracias!!!

Comment: Para eso que comentas lo mejor es usar este plugin para sincronizar las bases de datos :) https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db